# Create TabContainer dynamically and add it to accordion pane dynamically

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion, tabcontainer

I have created an accordion pane dynamically but now I want to add Ajax TabContainer to my accordion pane with multiple tabs but for some reason if I add multiple tabs it does not show but in my page source code it does show. If I add only one tab it does show but it does not show the controls I have added to it.

Here is my code:

```
'Create AccrionPane
Dim pane As New AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane
pane.ID = "pane_" & dt.Rows(i).Item("PRENR").ToString
pane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(headerLabel1)
pane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(headerLabel2)

'Create TabContainer
Dim tbContainer As New AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer
tbContainer.ID = "container_" & dt.Rows(i).Item("PRENR").ToString

'Create TabContent
Dim tbContent As New Control
tbContent.ID = "tbContent_" & dt.Rows(i).Item("PRENR").ToString

'Create TabPanel
Dim tbPanel As New AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel
tbPanel.ID = "tbPanel_" & dt.Rows(i).Item("PRENR").ToString
tbPanel.HeaderText = "PREMIUM AMOUNT"

'Adding the controls to Page
tbContent.Controls.Add(dvEarner1)
tbPanel.Controls.Add(tbContent)
tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel)
'tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel1)
'tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel2)
'tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel3)
'tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel4)
'tbContainer.Tabs.Add(tbPanel5)
pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(tbContainer)
Me.MainAccordion1.Panes.Add(pane)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I want to show DetailsViews in each tab in my accordion pane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it was an ID conflict situation.